# Getting Information on a Running Process in Windows Server?

Tags: c#, windows, process, taskmanager

I currently have a Windows process that is started by a user action on the web.  When this process starts, an item appears on the process list inside of task manager.  Sometimes I'll have three or four instances of the same process running.  Each of the instances of the process is associated with a job ID.

I use a push system where the process itself will ping a RESTful endpoint while it's doing its work (a la heartbeat).  I would like to use a pull system instead.  Is there a way for me to query Windows Task Manager through the command line and find out what job ID each of my process instances correspond to?

My process is written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible ways to implement inter-process communication is to use [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Each job process acts as a named pipe server with a name including the process id. The server, run in a separate thread, waits for a client connection and writes job id to the stream:

```
var jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
var jobIdBytes = jobId.ToByteArray();
var pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
var pipeName = "pipe" + pid;
var running = true;

new Thread(() =>
{
    using (var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName))
    {
        while (running)
        {
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            pipeServer.Write(jobIdBytes, 0, jobIdBytes.Length);
            pipeServer.Disconnect();
        }
    }

}).Start();
```

The application to query job ids will loop through all the running job processes, connect to their pipes and read job id from the stream:

```
var jobIdBytes = new byte[16];

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("jobProcessName"))
{
    var pipeName = "pipe" + process.Id;

    using (var clientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(pipeName))
    {
        clientStream.Connect();
        clientStream.Read(jobIdBytes, 0, jobIdBytes.Length);
    }

    var jobId = new Guid(jobIdBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("pid: {0}, job_id: {1}", process.Id, jobId));
}
```